# changing attribute of a tag with jquery in document.ready duplicate it

Tags: jquery

I have a `button input` and I'm going to disable it like this :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
                if ($('#participants tr').length < 3 )
                    jQuery("#send").attr('disabled', true);
                else
                    jQuery("#send").attr('disabled', false);
            });
```

It disables successfully but when enable condition is true,this part is duplicated in a nested way:

**Edit:**

```
<form>
 <fieldset>
 <table id="participants">
  ....
 </table>
  </fieldset>
</form>

<input type="button" value="send" onClick="sendMail()" id="send" />
<fieldset>
...
<form>
 <table id="participants">
    <tr>
      <td><a onClick='f(id)' >del</a></td>
    </tr>
 </table>
</form>
</fieldset>
<input type="button" value="send" onClick="sendMail()" id="send" />
```

this `table` has some rows of participants that each row has a del link that clicking it cause deleting participant from database and table,when number of rows in table is less than 3 I'm going to disable `send button`
why?

Comment: You have to be more clear. What does it duplicate?

Comment: i don't see anything thing in this code that makes it duplicate another button

Comment: @Purmou : Sorry! I edited the question.

Comment: where is your #participants tr 's , please add the HTML

Comment: table is into the form,take a look at question.

Comment: mmm your fieldset is incorrect , it should be inside form tag

Comment: @Kanishka Panamaldeniya :I tryed this,but it didn't work!

Answer (score 1):

try `removeAttr`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
                if ($('#participants tr').length < 3 )
                    jQuery("#send").attr('disabled', disabled);
                else
                    jQuery("#send").removeAttr('disabled');
            });
```

---

**UPDATE:**

i dont know what are you trying to achieve, you didn't disabled the button by default so enabling them at the DOM ready doesn't make sense i must be missing something, but from the code you have provided and what i understood from it, if you modify the markup as

```
<form>
 <fieldset>
 <table id="participants1">
  <tr>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
 </table>
  </fieldset>
    <input type="button" value="send" onClick="sendMail()" class="send" />
</form>
<fieldset>
<form>
 <table id="participants">
    <tr>
      <td>only one</td>
    </tr>
 </table>
    <input type="button" value="send" onClick="sendMail()" class="send" />
</form>
</fieldset>
```

notice that the ids are now unique and i have applied the class `send` to each send button, also i have taken the send button inside the form. The jquery part is as follow

```
$("form").each(function(){
 var $this = $(this);
 var trCount = $this.find("table tr").length;
    console.log(trCount);
    if(trCount>2){
        console.log($this.find(".send"));
    $this.find(".send").attr("disabled","disabled");
    }//else do nothing        
});
```

whats happening in the above code is its iterating through all the form elements on the page and looking for table inside them then the row count is checked and if exceeds the specified length it disabled that form's button..

## [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/4e2kH/3/)

Comment: @Asma , yes ou have 'participants' is duplicating , and also 'send' is duplicating , use a class instead of id

Comment: @Asma as Kanishka pointed out you have rather multiple duplicate ids the participant is repeating and also the id=save

Answer (score 0):

Check it out :
http://jquery-howto.blogspot.in/2008/12/how-to-disableenable-element-with.html

// To enable

```
$('#send').removeAttr('disabled');
```

// OR you can set attr to ""

```
$('#send').attr('disabled', '');
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of this

```
        if ($('#participants tr').length < 3 )
            jQuery("#send").attr('disabled', true);
        else
            jQuery("#send").attr('disabled', false);
```

try

```
$('#participants').each(function(){

      if ($(this).find('tr').ength < 3 )
             $(this).parents('fieldset').next("#send").attr('disabled', true);
      else
             $(this).parents('fieldset').next("#send").attr('disabled', false);

});
```